# Cloud Vision request failed

Tags: android, google-cloud-vision

I created an android app, where user is uploading images and i need to check them before getting upload for inappropriate contents. I created a Cloud Vision acc, created a project there, restricted it for Android app only by providing the package name and SHA1 fingerprint, then i got the API Key, enabled billing and Cloud Vision API too. Then in my android project i set that API. Now while testing i am getting the below error:

```
Request failed: {
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand in ***Requests ... are blocked.***?

Comment: there is nothing precisely defined to understand

Answer (score 0):

Why is your application name ? If you have specific limitations set on your API key, but your application is not properly identified, then it makes sense that it's rejected.

Please ensure that you have [properly enabled the API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/before-you-begin) first and make sure you created the correct [API key / service account](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth#top_of_page) for your code.

In fact, I think this [tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/blob/master/android/README.md) is probably easier as it's specifically designed for Android.